# Does it make any difference if we leave out "over" in "He has gone over to London"?

Tags: difference

What are the differences between

> He has gone over to London.

and

> He has gone to London.

I don't understand the differences these two sentences have.

Why in the first sentence is the word "**over**" used while in the other sentence it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a marker of informal speech that carries very little other meaning.

The very little meaning that the speaker/writer *might* intend is that the trip will take an unusual amount if time, either due to an unusually long stay or the distance to get there.

That difference in meaning is not certain though. It's vague and imprecise, which is part of why it's informal, and rarely is it deliberately chose—much more often it's said because it "feels" right. Whatever it might mean, it's a subtle enough implication that if the difference matters, the speaker or the listener should give or ask for more information:

> "He has gone over to London."
>   "Oh, for how long?"

Comment: I don't think "over" carries any special meaning with respect to time.  It conveys a notion of relative position.  If one thinks of the destination as being "over there" then one gets there by going *over* to it.  This might especially be the case when the destination is over a bridge, over the hills, over the ocean, or even, I suppose, over the road (as in a car travels over the road).

Comment: @Jim That's true of *down*/*up* and *in*/*out*, but never *over*/*under*. "He went over to Bill's desk" is correct when Bill's desk is on the same level. If you take the Tunnel to London from Paris, you never say "I went under to London last weekend" and *over* is still acceptable.

Comment: Compare "Bill came over (here) yesterday" with "Bill came here yesterday", when Bill lives mere feet away in the next apartment. The first communicates a visit of some length, the second doesn't.

Comment: yes, because you still think of Bill's desk and London as being not here, but "over there" And I still see no connection with time.  Bill came over here just long enough to hand me this letter.   Did Sue come here yesterday? Yes, she was here all day.

Comment: @Jim Yes, for distance it makes some sense, but it has nothing to do with having to go over things, else *under* would work too. Also consider: why "over there", not just "there"? It's the same odd construction, so you can't explain it using itself. There's just more to it than distance: for the letter example, notice you have to modify the time information to say it's short.

Comment: Notice that I said,*especially when* I didn't say only when.  We refer to lots of things as "over there" when you really don't go "up and over" to get there. Also, it's not distance it's relation so that anytime you'd describe something as being "*over* there" you can then use "go *over*" to describe the action of getting there.  (Also, if you can describe something as being "under there", you can use "go under" to describe the action of going there.) But if you wouldn't describe the thing as being "*over* there" then you can't use "go *over*" to get there.

Comment: I think you've done a good job taking a stab at this, but it's tricky to pin down. In addition to a long time, it could also be used to hint at a long distance. Someone in the U.S. might "go to Chicago" one week, and then "go over to London" the next. Sure, one could use "over" in the first case, and omit it in the second, but it might seem a bit more natural to use "over" when referring to the intercontinental travel.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not what is meant here, but one possible meaning of *go over* is to change one's allegiance.    So, for instance, if the person being spoken of were a Russian spy, then *He has gone to London* would simply mean that he has traveled there for some reason, but *He has gone over to London* would suggest that he has defected.

Answer (score 2):

I think people would only use the first sentence if "he" wasn't in England in the first place, and he went over the English channel (or possibly across the Atlantic Ocean) to London.

I've checked a sample of instances of "gone over to London" from Google books (there are very few in total), and the people who went over all started out from places other than England and Scotland. You can find a number from America, and others from Italy, Holland, and Ireland.

Answer (score 1):

You generally use Gone over when you are going to someones house. For eg. I had gone over to Tom's place for borrowing a few books.

If you ware saying you went to a city, its correct usage would be - I had gone to London.

You dont use the OVER when you talk of cities.

Comment: That may not be used as city. It can also be used as an area, a land at somewhere.

Comment: Agreed. I would still say that a place like A city/area/street will not use Over . Its only used when you are talking about going to someone's house.

Comment: If you were in France, and talking about somebody who went to London, you could use *over* because they crossed the English channel.